# What is a generic solution to factor $\alpha x^6 - \beta x^4+\gamma x^2 -\delta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm curious if there exists a generic solution /approach to factor the polynomial 
$\alpha x^6 - \beta x^4+\gamma x^2 -\delta $ with $\alpha \beta \gamma \delta$ the coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: You may set $x^2 = u$ to get a cubic:
$\alpha u^3 - \beta u^2 + \gamma u - \delta$

Comment: And this cubic can be solved exactly

Comment: @Dietrich: edited the question

Comment: @NeverStopLearning Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

There is sometimes an alternative. The demand that roots come in $\pm$ pairs is pretty restrictive, though.

This first type is well behaved, example

$$ ( x^2 - 2)  ( x^2 - 3)  ( x^2 - 5 ) =  x^6 - 10x^4 + 31x^2 - 30 $$
There are six real roots, square roots of things. The general pattern would be
$$ (x^2 - a)(x^2 - b)(x^2 - c) = x^6 - (a+b+c)x^4 + (bc + ca + ab)x^2 - abc.$$
If $a,b,c$ are all positive, real roots.

We could also have $$  (x^2 - a)(x^4 + b x^2 + c) $$
with both factors irreducible over the rationals, say.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Let
$$  x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c  $$
have no rational roots, just be really unpleasant. We still get your
$$ \left(x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c \right)\left(x^3 - a x^2 + b x - c \right)= x^6 + (2b-a^2) x^4 + (b^2 - 2ac) x^2 - c^2 $$

Here is a good one

$$ \left(x^3 +  x^2 -12 x + 11 \right)\left(x^3 -  x^2 -12 x - 11 \right)= x^6 -25 x^4 +122x^2 - 121 $$

The first cubic was constructed using the cyclotomic methods of Gauss. Its roots are sums of cosines

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let $y=x^2$

$$x^6 - \alpha x^4+\beta x^2 -\gamma\iff y^3 - \alpha x^2+\beta y -\gamma$$

and solve the [**cubic formula**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html).

Comment: Yes, this is clear, but how to get to the factors? Like $F(y^2) = G(y)*G(-y)$

Comment: For the cubic a general solution exists, you need to use that and then calculate $x$ such that $x^2=y$. I can’t see others general approaches to that.

Comment: gimusi example $ \left(x^3 +  x^2 -12 x + 11 \right)\left(x^3 -  x^2 -12 x - 11 \right)= x^6 -25 x^4 +122x^2 - 121 $

Comment: @WillJagy nice trick, I didn't consider that possibility since I was focused on the general case. Thanks

Comment: $ ( x^2 - 2)  ( x^2 - 3)  ( x^2 - 5 ) =  x^6 - 10x^4 + 31x^2 - 30 $

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $t=x^2$ to get $\alpha x^6 - \beta x^4+\gamma x^2 -\delta= \alpha t^3 - \beta t^2+\gamma t -\delta$, then solve the cubic equation using cardano's formula

Answer (score 0):

Set $y=x^2$. Then $y^3-ay^2+by-c=0$ can be easily tested for a linear factor in $y$. 
Also, one can solve the cubic equation in $y$.

Comment: $$ ( x^2 - 2)  ( x^2 - 3)  ( x^2 - 5 ) =  x^6 - 10x^4 + 31x^2 - 30 $$

$$ \left(x^3 +  x^2 -12 x + 11 \right)\left(x^3 -  x^2 -12 x - 11 \right)= x^6 -25 x^4 +122x^2 - 121 $$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wanted to say a factor in $y$, not in $x$, sorry.

Comment: I thought about it overnight, and I still have not worked out a careful collection of all possible rational-reducible sextics of the type given. I did realize that my 2,3,5 example was pretty much exactly what you had in mind; so, sorry on my part. The product of two cubics does seem to be different, the actual roots in a different sort of extension field.